# HTML/CSS dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have problem with setting up dropdowns. When I click on button small menu will show up but when I try links it does nothing. I have tried pointer events and look for something above the links, what could hide those links from my clicking but I still can not figgure it out what it might be.

html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MainPage</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="Nav">
            <p class="Name">HokusPokus</p>
            <div class="Buttons">
                <button><a href="home" class="home">Home</a></button>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button>User</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="login">Login</a>
                        <a href="register">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

````
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 250);
}

.Name{
    color:rgb(254, 95, 85);
    position:relative;
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:Arial;
    margin:0px 20px;
    padding:10px
}
.Nav{
    background-color: rgb(73, 88, 103);
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    height:80px
}
.Buttons{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex
}

.dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  right:150px
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: rgb(87, 115, 153);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding:10px; 
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(254, 95, 85);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Buttons button,a{
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor:pointer
}
.dropdown button:focus + .dropdown-content {
  display:block;
}

.MainDiv{margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:200px;
  width:320px;
  height:500px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 4px rgb(87, 115, 153);
  background-color: rgb(87, 115, 153);
  padding:30px}

.Nadpis{
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:arial;}
.Input{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because when we click on the link we click outside the button focus so based on your CSS it turn the dropdown-content to display:none and close the bow before the link is followed.

To prove my point I added a display block on dorpdown-content:hover and it seems to solve it. Try changing that and let me know if it solves your problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 250);
}

.Name{
    color:rgb(254, 95, 85);
    position:relative;
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:Arial;
    margin:0px 20px;
    padding:10px
}
.Nav{
    background-color: rgb(73, 88, 103);
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    height:80px
}
.Buttons{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex
}

.dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  right:150px
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: rgb(87, 115, 153);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding:10px; 
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(254, 95, 85);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Buttons button,a{
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor:pointer
}
.dropdown button:focus + .dropdown-content {
  display:block;
}
.dropdown-content:hover{
  display:block;
}

.MainDiv{margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:200px;
  width:320px;
  height:500px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 4px rgb(87, 115, 153);
  background-color: rgb(87, 115, 153);
  padding:30px}

.Nadpis{
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:arial;}
.Input{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MainPage</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="Nav">
            <p class="Name">HokusPokus</p>
            <div class="Buttons">
                <button><a href="home" class="home">Home</a></button>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button>User</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="login" target="_blank">Login</a>
                        <a href="register">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```